# Scrape an entire API or rely heavily on it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, api-design

I'm building a resort review site in rails. Currently, a `User` has many reviews, and each `Review` belongs to a `User`.

The reviews table contains an `expedia_id` field. All data - the hotel name, images, description, etc. are pulled dynamically from the Expedia API, using lookups against this id. For example, when hitting the `show` action in a controller, it makes a request to Expedia **and** my db using the `expedia_id` to get all of the reviews and content, and renders everything on one page. Requests will also made to populate the home page (I'm thinking a `Featured` table with an `expedia_id` column)

Since my entire website relies heavily on an API and I don't have a `Resort` table, plus the fact that given a large amount of users, **a lot** of requests would be made to the Expedia API, would it make sense to scrape and write the results to my database, creating records for later use?

Comment: There is a middle ground,  where you create a `resorts` table in your database, with the fields you want plus an `expire_datetime`. When you try to access a `resort` you don't have, or is `expired` you make an api request to Expedia, caching the results in your database, and updating the `expire_datetime`.

Comment: comment by @MichaelGorman IS the answer to this question.

Comment: @MichaelGorman I agree with Josep, you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: In addition to @MichaelGorman's comment and answer, you need a task that periodically sweeps the table and confirms/updates/purges records otherwise it will only grow and will contain stale information. `rails runner` would be a good way to fire off jobs for that.

Comment: @theTinMan yes that would be a good optimization, something like any `resort` that has an `expire_date > 1.month` (hasn't been touched for at least a month) gets `deleted` (note this would need to be delete not destroy as destroy would initialize the record, and attempt an update)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The middle ground would be the best solution.
Create a table and model that would locally store the active resorts.  Expiring your local copy after a certain period (determined by how frequently the resorts change on Expedia) and only pinging the api on a new to your system resort, or loading a resort that has been expired

This would be a basic example of how this might be done

```
class Resort < ApplicationRecord #for Rails <=4 do ActiveRecord::Base
  after_find :maybe_update_from_expedia
  ExpirationTime = 1.day #change to fit what is needed

  def self.find_by_expedia_id(expedia_id)
    result = self.where(expedia_id: expedia_id).first
    result || self.create_by_expedia_id(expedia_id)
  end

  def maybe_update_from_expedia
    update_from_expedia if expire_at.nil? || expire_at < Time.now
  end

  private
  def self.create_by_expedia_id(expedia_id)
    record = new(expedia_id: expedia_id)
    record.maybe_update_from_expedia
    record
  end

  def update_from_expedia
    #fetch record from expedia
    #update local data
    self.expire_time = Time.now + ExpirationTime
    self.save
  end
end
```

As suggested by [engineersmnky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1978251/engineersmnky) this can be condensed to

```
class Resort < ApplicationRecord #for Rails <=4 do ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :maybe_update_from_expedia
  ExpirationTime = 1.day #change to fit what is needed

  private

  def maybe_update_from_expedia
    update_from_expedia if expire_at.nil? || expire_at < Time.now
  end

  def update_from_expedia
    #fetch record from expedia
    #update local data
    self.expire_time = Time.now + ExpirationTime
    self.save
  end
end
```

If all fetch requests use `Resort.find_or_create_by(expedia_id: expedia_id)`

Comment: Any reason we are not using `find_or_create_by(expedia_id: expedia_id)`. it just seems like you are duplicating a lot of out of the box `rails` code

Comment: I remember having issues with `find_or_create_by` not firing the `after_initialize` callback, but that may have been on the older rails environments I find my self in most of the time

Comment: Very well. It keeps the model thinner but after reflection I think the transparency here makes more sense as a formal answer. Well Done

Comment: thanks, if we can be sure `find_or_create_by` or `find_or_initialize_by` does hit the `after_initialize` call back it would make the code alot cleaner.

Comment: A little research suggests that it should always hit the callback, so I added the condensed version, with the full one to help explain what is going on